# PHP MVC, who owns the URLs?

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller, architecture, model

I am implementing a PHP application using MVC technique. A brief introduction for loading `http://site/photos/25?options` which rewrites to `http://site/index.php?page=photos&id=25&options`:

- `index.php` -> instantiates and calls `PhotoController` object
- `PhotoController` instantiates `PhotoView` and loads correct `Photo` (model) into it
- `PhotoController` calls `PhotoView->render()`, and header/footer views
- `PhotoView` has access to the `Photo` model and other model data it needs

The `PhotoView` will output the HTML and wants to hyperlink to different pages. When that view generates hyperlinks I am confused about which layer should own URLs. Options I see are outlined below. Please help me choose the right approach.

---

**Model Layer Owns URLs**

> Models have a `getURL()` method

Advantages:

- The base `View` class could incorporate Open Graph properties
- `PhotoView` could do this: `$folderHref = $photo->getFolder()->url`

Disadvantages:

- Some controllers do not have a single corresponding model, like `LoginController`, `AdminController`, how would I get URLs for these?

---

**Controller Owns URLs**

> Controllers have `url` and `title` properties. To create a link, the presenting controller creates target controllers and passes to the view. The view accesses the `url` and `title` from the passed object.

Advantages:

- Every URL directly maps to a controller (in `index.php`), so the converse seems clean

Disadvantages:

- A view that needs URLs for other views will need one of the following ugly hacks:

  - Querying an unrelated controller `$folderHref = Controllers\FolderController::urlForFolder($photo->getFolder())`
  - Views knowing too much about their controllers `$folderHref = $photo->getFolder()->getControllerAndSetURL()->getURL()`
  - Excessive communication between a view and its controller `$folderHref = $this->delegate->getURLForFolder($photo->getFolder())` and `$adminHref = $this->delegate->getURLForAdminHref()` with `delegate` having many methods

---

**Everybody owns URLs**

> A base class `OpenGraphObject` is the parent class for `Controllers` AND `Models` and has a method `getURL()`

`Controllers` and `Models` implement this only if it can be run without arguments. (E.g. `PhotoController` returns NULL because the URL depends on which `Photo` will show).

Advantages:

- Every advantage above

Disadvantages

- Confusion
- Revocation of my programming license

Comment: have you looked at codeigniter or other mvc framework? all that work is done for you although this very interesting.

Comment: I'm not sure what Open Graph properties are. Can you please provide a concrete example of expected html rendered by the View and which other objects your app involves to produce that?

Comment: OpenGraphObject is just a class with properties for the Open Graph specification http://ogp.me/ e.g. $title, $url, $image, $type

Comment: Just studied the CodeIgniter approach, it looks like they use hard coding and a utility class, e.g. `echo base_url("blog/post/123");`. Of course here `blog` and `post` are hard coded. Probably not a bad idea buts breaks MVC IMHO.

Comment: Usefull info on "mvc" http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2014/11/a-beginners-guide-to-mvc-for-web.html - I would recommend reading that.

Answer (score 0):

To separate concerns I would break it down like this:

```
/**
 * Responsible for processing and rendering user output
 */
interface View {

    public function render();
}

/**
 * Used just to further formalize the messages between Photo and View
 */
interface PhotoView extends View {

    public function setPhotoData($id, $title, $link);
}

/**
 * Among other things knows how to generate URLs to routes
 */
interface Router {

    /**
     * Returns the URL to route based on route name
     * @param string $routeName
     * @param array $params
     */
    public function urlTo($routeName, $params = null);
}
```

I'm not going to implement every class, there are plenty off the shelf solutions you can use, for template engine and router for example.

An example controller to display an image based on id can be:

```
class PhotoController {

    public function displayAction($photoId) {
        $photo = Photo::findById($photoId);

        $templateFile = $this->pathTo('photo-template.php');

        //can be a singleton for example, it holds all the routes for the application
        //and knows how to render them based on the name and parameters
        $router = AppRouter::instance();

        return $photo->render(new ConcretePhotoView($templateFile, $router));
    }

}
```

In this example Photo needs to be able to fetch itself from the DB and then render itself to the PhotoView:

```
class Photo {

    private $id;
    private $title;
    private $sourceLink;

    //other methods...

    public function render(PhotoView $view) {
        $view->setPhotoData($this->id, $this->title, $this->sourceLink);

        return $view->render();
    }

}
```

Let's say the HTML template `photo-template.php` looks like this:

```
<a href="<?= $userLogin['href'] ?>"><?= $userLogin['label'] ?></a>
<a href="<?= $userRegister['href'] ?>"><?= $userRegister['label'] ?></a>
<div>
    <img src="<?= $photo['src'] ?>" title="<?= $photo['title'] ?>" />
    <a href="<?= $photoLink['href'] ?>"><?= $photoLink['label'] ?></a>
</div>
```

It should be clear enough what variables this template needs. No logic in it, just pure displaying although some basic control would be ok.

All that is left is to code the ConcretePhotoView which will use the provided template file and the router to adapt the data between domain object Photo and the concrete html template:

```
class ConcretePhotoView implements PhotoView {

    private $templateEngine;
    private $router;

    public function __construct($templateFile, Router $router) {
        $this->templateEngine = new SomeTemplateEngine($templateFile);
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    public function render() {
        //router has a route userLogin with no params
        $this->templateEngine->assign('userLogin', array(
            'href' => $this->router->urlTo('userLogin'),
            'label' => 'Login'
        ));

        $this->templateEngine->assign('userRegister', array(
            //router has a route named userRegister that requires no params
            'href' => $this->router->urlTo('userRegister'),
            'label' => 'Register'
        ));

        return $this->templateEngine->render();
    }

    public function setPhotoData($id, $title, $link) {
        $this->templateEngine->assign('photo', array(
            'src' => $link,
            'title' => $title
        ));

        $this->templateEngine->assign('photoLink', array(
            //router has a route named photo that requires an id
            'href' => $this->router->urlTo('photo', array('id' => $id)),
            'label' => $title
        ));
    }

}
```

Finally to answer the question "Who owns the URLs?" - the Router. That knowledge is encapsulated there and is specific to application configuration. Other objects use it to generate links.

Comment: Your controller seems to be doing things that it should not be responsible for (like using manipulating active records, choosing templates and rendering views). And there is the clear use of singleton **anti-pattern**. But lets disregard all this ... because what I really do not understand is: where in the real world you have had a need to generate URLs base on the router for the templates? When have you dealt with URLs that completely change (not just the ID part) in different contexts for the same template?

Comment: My understanding is when an objects tells another object to do the work for it, it is not doing the actual work. The controller is delegating the rendering to the View and also the DB fetching to other object. It does not doing the actual work. I guess knowing the path to the views might be moved to the actual View so the controller knows even less. 
As for use of Singleton it seems reasonable to me that we have a single Router per application. Can you please elaborate a bit more on URLs and template remark, didn't understand that. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: IMO the controller would have been doing the HTML rendering and the Db fetching if it for example actually had the html tags and the SQL queries in it.

Comment: No, it is actually worse, because you take a active record instance, pass **to it** a template and then your controller renders the AR instance.

Comment: And that is bad why? The Photo is encapsulated, it knows how to render itself using the PhotoView. If you'd like Photo delegates the rendering to the PhotoView. Controller just passes the right messages around.

Comment: Are you aware that you domain entities now depend on the implementation of UI layer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65787/discussion-between-nikola-and-teresko).